Best practices for using @property with Enum values on a Django model for DRF serialization
Question: I'm looking for guidance on using @property on a Django model, particularly when the property returns an Enum value and needs to be exposed in a Django REST Framework (DRF) serializer. Here’s my setup:
I’ve defined an Enum, AccountingType, to represent the possible accounting types:
from enum import Enum

class AccountingType(Enum):
    ASSET = "Asset"
    LIABILITY = "Liability"
    UNKNOWN = "Unknown"

On my Account model, I use a @property method to determine the accounting_type based on existing fields:
# Account fields ...

@property
def accounting_type(self) -> AccountingType:
    """Return the accounting type for this account based on the account sub type."""
    if self.account_sub_type in constants.LIABILITY_SUB_TYPES:
        return AccountingType.LIABILITY

    if self.account_sub_type in constants.ASSET_SUB_TYPES:
        return AccountingType.ASSET

    return AccountingType.UNKNOWN

In Django views, I can use this property directly without issues. For example:
account = Account.objects.get(id=some_id)
if account.accounting_type == AccountingType.LIABILITY:
    print("This account is a liability.")

Problem: When trying to expose accounting_type in DRF, using serializers.ReadOnlyField() does not include the property in the serialized output:
class AccountDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    accounting_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['accounting_type', 'account_id', ...]

I found that switching to serializers.SerializerMethodField() resolves the issue, allowing me to return the Enum value as a string:
class AccountDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    accounting_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['accounting_type', 'account_id', ...]

    def get_accounting_type(self, obj):
        return obj.accounting_type.value  # Return the Enum value as a string

Questions:

Is there a reason serializers.ReadOnlyField() doesn’t work with @property when it returns an Enum? Does DRF handle @property fields differently based on the return type?
Is SerializerMethodField the recommended approach when a property returns a complex type, like an Enum, that needs specific serialization?
Are there best practices for exposing Enum values via model properties in DRF?

Any insights would be appreciated.


Is there a reason serializers.ReadOnlyField() doesn’t work with @property when it returns an Enum?

An Enum can not be JSON serialized. Make the AccountingType json serializable by making it a subclass of str as well:
class AccountingType(str, Enum):
    ASSET = 'Asset'
    LIABILITY = 'Liability'
    UNKNOWN = 'Unknown'
then it is sufficient to work with a ReadOnlyField:
class AccountDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    accounting_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    # …
Alternatively, we can just obtain the .value from the AccountingType:
class AccountDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    accounting_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='accountingtype.value')

    # …

Thank you this is really helpful. Side question, is Enum better practice in this context?

@Prometheus: if there are a certain number of values I would think yes, but the AccountingType(str, Enum) is still an enum, but it now also acts as a string, and thus "fools" the JSON serializer in thinking it knows how to serialize the enum (well "fools" is probably not a good word, since it is in fact a string).

Thank you. I deciced to used source='accountingtype.value' but above makes sense.

If you're working with Enums frequently, you can create a custom DRF field to handle Enum serialization:
class EnumField(serializers.Field):
def to_representation(self, value):
    return value.value if isinstance(value, Enum) else value

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    raise NotImplementedError("EnumField is read-only.")

Use case:
class AccountDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
accounting_type = EnumField()

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ['accounting_type', 'account_id', ...]

